# How to only bold characters from content control usinng vba?

Tags: excel, vba, word-contentcontrol

I am trying to transfer number of content controls to excel spreadsheet. The issue is, I would only like to transfer words which were selected by used with bold. I would appreciate any help.

I have already tried to adopt one of your workflows but I am stuck.

```
Dim txtboxstring As Characters
Dim CharacterFont As Font
Dim counter As Integer

(...)
ElseIf C_C.Title = "Data_Sheet_Structural_Type" Then
    Workbooks(DES_Bridges_WrkBook).Sheets(DES_Bridges_WrkSheet).Cells(i, 17).Value = C_C.Range.Text

    'Test for bold text
ElseIf C_C.Title = "Data_Sheet_Material" Then
    Set textboxstring = C_C.Range.Characters

    For counter = 1 To textboxstring.Count
        CharacterFont = textboxstring.Font
        If CharacterFont.Bold Then
            BoldFound = BoldFound & txtboxstring(counter)
        End If
    Next counter

    Workbooks(DES_Bridges_WrkBook).Sheets(DES_Bridges_WrkSheet).Cells(i, 18).Value = BoldFound
    BoldFound = ""
ElseIf C_C.Title = "Deck_Width" Then
    Workbooks(DES_Bridges_WrkBook).Sheets(DES_Bridges_WrkSheet).Cells(i, 19).Value = C_C.Range.Text

(...)
```

I get following error:

> Objec doesnt support Property or Method

in line

```
CharacterFont = textboxstring.Font
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please make your issue easier to replicate. Just few lines of code where you get error, easy to copy and analyse.

Comment: What is `C_C`? Please give a full [mcve].